# How do websites encrypt API response?

Tags: api, encryption, hex

When we see API response of some big websites in google chrome network tab we see an encrypted response from the server. The response is nothing but a hex code. My question is how do they encrypt and decrypt the response?

This is a part of a response from an API

```
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
```

Comment: Request and response is by default encrypted usingTLS (https). Where do you see this type of response? imho data are only encoded, as additional encryption would make any sense (the client would need to possess the decryption anyway)

Answer (score 2):

That's not encrypted nor is it [hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). That's just [Base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). It's a RIFF image:

```
$ echo "..." | base64 -D > x
$ file x
RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image, VP8 encoding, 140x312, Scaling: [none]x[none], YUV color, decoders should clamp
```

Seems like it's transparent, though. Use Chrome to open it.